# Understanding ASAN summary

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

The example below is from an ASAN report caused by `heap-use-after-free on address 0x6040000a06b0`
How would I be able to tell that this was a heap use after free error solely from looking at this summary?

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:826 in __interceptor_memcmp
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c088000c080: fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c088000c090: fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c088000c0a0: fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c088000c0b0: fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 fa
  0x0c088000c0c0: fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 fa
=>0x0c088000c0d0: fa fa fa fa fd fd[fd]fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 fa
  0x0c088000c0e0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c088000c0f0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c088000c100: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c088000c110: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c088000c120: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
```

In greater scope, I am wondering what information I should be extracting and how do I interpret what the error is specifically from the above summary. 
Would one be able to preemptively see additional ASAN errors if they happened to appear in this summary?

Answer (score 2):

Each 8-byte chunk of user memory is mapped to single byte of Asan's shadow memory. If this 8-byte chunk contains valid data shadow byte will have 0, 1, ... or 7. Any other value tells Asan runtime that memory is invalid i.e. it was freed or stack frame was deallocated or something like that. In particular `fd` means that this address `0x6040000a06b0` points to freed heap buffer (same is true for preceeding 8 bytes btw - it's also marked with `fd`).

Details about particular values are explained at the end of error message:

```
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
```

To your other question, main error message is

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:826 in __interceptor_memcmp
```

It tells you error type and it's location in code.

Normally it will also report full stacktrace for `free()` call and historical stacktrace for original `malloc()` call (I'm not sure why they are not includedin your message).